# Directories that exist - Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net, directory

How would I be able to make a variable that holds the value of the directories that exist in the C:\?

Comment: We need a bit more clarification to answer.  Do you want just the directories at the root level, or do you want the ones several levels seep?  And if you want more than the root, do you need to retain the structure (ie folder/sub folder relationships)?

Answer (score 3):

The [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo_members.aspx) class has member functions to do that - GetDirectories in this case.

> ```
> Imports System.IO
>
> Dim fTarget As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\")
> Dim arrAnswer as DirectoryInfo()
> arrAnswer = fTarget.GetDirectories()
> ```

Comment: Yep.  And technically, you can create a variable of the type DirectoryInfo

Comment: Aye, if you really wanted to see a whole folder tree, you'd want to write a function and call it recursively to populate an array of names, probably with an extra column to reflect it's parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to call GetDirectories on the static type Directory. This can be found in System.Io. It returns a string array of directories that it finds. You can also specify if it should drill down into subcategories when it  is called

See msdn for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories.aspx